# List open workbooks minus current workbook

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have implemented the following code that lists the names of all open workbooks within a ComboBox:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
If Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex < 0 Then
Me.CommandButton2.Enabled = False
Else
Me.CommandButton2.Enabled = True
End If
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
MsgBox "Are you sure you want to select " & Me.ComboBox1.BoundValue, vbOKOnly
Application.Workbooks(Me.ComboBox1.Value).Activate
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim myWin As Window
Dim wkbk As Workbook

With Me.ComboBox1
.Style = fmStyleDropDownList
End With

With Me.CommandButton1
.Caption = "Cancel"
.Enabled = True
.Cancel = True
.TakeFocusOnClick = False
End With

With Me.CommandButton2
.Enabled = False
.Default = True
.Caption = "Activate Workbook"
.TakeFocusOnClick = False

End With

Me.Caption = "Please select a workbook"

For Each wkbk In Application.Workbooks
For Each myWin In wkbk.Windows
If myWin.Visible = True Then
Me.ComboBox1.AddItem wkbk.Name

Exit For
End If
Next myWin
Next wkbk

End Sub
```

This works great but also lists the current workbook at the top of the list. Is there a way I can exclude the current workbook from the list?

I have tried implementing the following on a ComboBox drop down click event but not having much luck.

```
ComboBox1.RemoverItem ("Workbook.xls")
```

Cheers

Comment: Add an `if not thisworkbook`?

Comment: `If Not wkbk.Name = Thisworkbook.Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment.

```
For Each wkbk In Application.Workbooks
If not wkbk.name =thisworkbook.name then
For Each myWin In wkbk.Windows
If myWin.Visible = True Then
Me.ComboBox1.AddItem wkbk.Name
Exit For
End If
Next myWin
end if
Next wkbk
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I've tried the code and it gets hung up at "Next wkbk" with a compile error "Next without For"